# Converting the a date value (String) to timestamp with a different timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a date value like this:

```
$date_value = "2016-12-10 11:28:36";
```

My TimeZone is `Asia/Tehran`, which has 3:30 offset from GMT (so it becomes GTM3:30+). I saved my content at `14:58` but it save the item with the above value (`$date_value`), which sounds logical, as it used server timezone which how no offset from GMT (GMT00).

Now, I want to convert back the date into my desired timezone which is "Asia/Tehran", but my date procedure does not work as expected (by "expected I mean it does not convert the date time back to 14:59:00) which is a Tehran's based time. Here is the code I use:

```
$DateTime = new DateTime($date_value, new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));

print $DateTime->format($format); // edited the question with on this line
```

But it prints back the exact date, as if there is no change.

It always work, but I don't know why it does not work for this specific case. I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: It doesn't work how?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Yes, My mistake. I mean format()

Comment: I'm not really familiar with timezones but maybe `format` doesn't take timezone into consideration? If you use `$format = 'd.m.Y H:i:sP';` you can see that there's proper `+03:30` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date string that you retrieve from the server is UTC, you should construct your `DateTime` object in UTC and then change the timezone.

```
$format = "Y-m-d H:i:s";
$date_value = "2016-12-10 11:28:36";

$DateTime = new DateTime($date_value, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$DateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
print $DateTime->format($format);

// Outputs: 2016-12-10 14:58:36
```

Comment: the key was "UTC". Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

Create DateTime object from string:

```
$date_value = "2016-12-10 11:28:36";
$date = new DateTime($date_value);
```

Set timezone:

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
```

Get and format date:

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s (e) P') . "\n";
```

This code shows how it works when you change timezone in DateTime object:

```
<?php
$date_value = "2016-12-10 11:28:36";

$date = new DateTime($date_value);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s (e) P') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s  (e) P') . "\n";
```

Output:

```
2016-12-10 22:58:36 (Asia/Tehran) +03:30
2016-12-10 20:28:36  (Europe/Warsaw) +01:00
```

More information you can read here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

(your code doesn't work because timezone parameter in DateTime constructor method create date in this specified timezone)